# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error using Firestore without Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, sdk, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error when using Firestore without Cocoapods.

I follow everything in Firebase SDK Readme and this is what I've got!
[Firestore Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opx5y.jpg)

The full log is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y9nK4ghFbWzfMl5uUByA5KgR-mXJ7dVACmECrzwZ1Jc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your error message, please add the actual code and error message as text to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried. It's a 3000++ characters long error message. Stackoverflow limit it to 3000max.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y9nK4ghFbWzfMl5uUByA5KgR-mXJ7dVACmECrzwZ1Jc/edit?usp=sharing this is the full log.

Comment: Looks like the Link Binary With Libraries Build Phase is missing libc++.

Comment: I have libc++ installed

```Last login: Wed Dec 13 15:47:50 on console
Taylor:~ zulwiyozaputra$ clang++ --version
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
Taylor:~ zulwiyozaputra$ 
```